# Find a Date from last year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I am trying to calculate two dates from a year ago. Let’s say if today it is 3/18/13, I need to find 4/1/12 and also find 4/30/12.

I tried the following which gives me 4/18/12, but not sure how to get the desired dates mentioned above. Also, I need to find   5/1/12, 5/31/12…  etc.  Any idea ?  thanks.

```
DATEADD(MONTH,-11, GETDATE())    -  returns 4/18/12
```

I also tried

```
DATEADD(YEAR,-1, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,-11, GETDATE()), 0)) It returns  4/1/12 ,
DATEADD(YEAR,-1, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,-10, GETDATE()), 0)) also returns 4/1/12 instead of   5/1/12
```

Comment: Why do you need to *calculate* them? Is it just a training exercise? If so, you may want to use a combination of `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` by getting number of days since Jan 1st and then adding this number to get the desired date.  This logic will be independent of the current date - if this's OK.

Comment: Can you confirm you want the start and end of the next month from today's date, but from a year ago? A good description of the overall requirements would help.

Comment: yes, the start and end of the next month from today's date, but from a year ago.  It is not for training exercise, but for a report that I am creating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is the first and last day of the following month from one year ago today, something like this might work:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month,-11,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0) )
SELECT DATEADD(month,-11,DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())+1,0))))
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there is a more efficient way of doing this.  The article at [examples of how to Calculate Different SQL Server Dates](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3076421/Examples-of-how-to-Calculate-Different-SQL-Server-Dates.htm) discusses these kinds of calculations.